# Python Split lines/words from input files into variables

Tags: python

I very new to Python and I want to do the following:
I am creating a script that is doing for example a ssh login to devices to check all kind of things (capacity, uptime etc.)
I want open a file for reading, read the first line and put every word into a variable for later use.
I have been searching and trying but no result.

input file is: `input.file`

example:
Varables are: DevType, ManuF, ip, Serial

```
server   Dell   172.0.0.1   abc123   
storage  IBM    172.0.0.2   w2q3r4134  
network  Cisco  172.0.0.3   vf578WWr
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: you can't just write the question and waiting for the code... at least write some lines

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. As many users already pointed out, we encourage people to share what they've accomplished so far. This helps everybody (you included), providing effort that is on point. Please, have a read here on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

`open` the file, iterate over lines, `split()` without argument to split over whitespace.

```
with open("input.file") as f:
    for line in f:
        dev_type, manuf, ip, serial = line.strip().split()
        print((dev_type, manuf, ip, serial))
```

Comment: It is working, thank you very much This is helping me a lot.